# Conditional Logic Inside XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to write a component which will show rating via the number of star images it will hold, for example put 5 stars for a rating of 5. Is there a way I can define creation of these stars as a for loop in the XAML or do have to do it programatically in the code behind? What I am asking basically is that, is there a way to incorporate conditional logic inside the XAML?

Comment: You may wanna look at the [Rating](https://wpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Toolkit-release/Input/Rating/System/Windows/Controls/Rating.cs) component.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to incorporate conditional logic inside the XAML?

Yes and no. You can use [DataTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)s which will be actioned if a condition is met, but that is unnecessary for what you need to do.

I would use a list control, and in the content template for the items have an Image control that uses a star as its source. Bind this list control to a collection (i.e. `List<int>`) that has one item per star. If it is possible to have fractions of stars then this approach would be best - use a `List<decimal>` instead of int, then adjust your item template to show the appropriate image for the fractional number.

Alternatively if you just have an `int` property that contains the number of stars, then there are two approaches:

- have an Image control that has *max stars + 1* DataTriggers, and you set the source of the image to the appropriate image file. This is a somewhat suboptimal method because all the DataTriggers get evaluated.
- use an Image control with a Converter that returns the appropriate Source URI based on the number of stars.

Comment: I like the idea about the list control. I wonder if it makes sense to use a converter there though. i.e. instead of binding to a List<int>, just bind to an int with the rating, and let the converter change that rating to a collection with something like `Enumerable.Range(1, rating)`. Just a thought that might make the code feel a bit more natural.

Comment: @rmc00 It depends on how/where you are showing the stars. If you are simply showing a detail page where the stars will be shown/rendered just once then any of these options are viable. If you're showing a whole list of items that have stars then the DataTrigger approach will become noticeably slower the more you have, while the converter approach will be faster because it takes a fixed amount of time per item to determine how many stars to show.

Comment: I actually posted a complete implementation of such a control in an answer a few months ago. Quick and fun to write. The number of stars wasn't parameterized, though (maybe should have written it a little slower). Maybe I can find it.